# How to automatically copy files when created in box.com to Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, box

How to automatically copy files when created in box.com folder to a specific location in Azure blob storage?

Is this possible with [Microsoft Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible.

Check the Box.com [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/box/). There is a trigger called [When a file is created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/box/#when-a-file-is-created). You can then copy your file to a blob storage.

So

1. Create a box.com account.
2. Create an Azure storage account and a blob container.
3. Create an Azure logic app and read some tutorial :-)